# How to create a separated menu with logo in between

Tags: html, css

**EDIT:** Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/tp27e67L/

I'm trying to create a menu from a mockup design, I originally drew it with 3 menu items on each side of the logo but I'm having real troubles with executing this idea with css.

This menu is created via wordpress so I can't customize the html without using custom scripts (which I had to do to get the logo to show up where it does). The menu must be a single menu, so I can't split it up into 2 menus and just putting the logo in between etc.

I tried using `display` `table`, `table-row` and `table-cell` but it's not even close to what I'm trying to achieve.

This is how it should look like:

[image: menu mockup]

This is how my (somewhat incomplete) attempt looks like:

[image: menu fail]

Here's my attempt:

```
<div id="desktop-nav">
  <ul id="desktop-nav-menu" class="clearfix no-bullet">
    <li id="menu-item-29" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-29">Hem</li>
    <li id="menu-item-27" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-27">Aktiviteter</li>
    <li id="menu-item-26" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-26">Konferenser</li>
    <li id="menu-item-31" class="site-logo menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-31"></li>
    <li id="menu-item-28" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-28">Priser</li>
    <li id="menu-item-25" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-25">Om oss</li>
    <li id="menu-item-24" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-24">Kontakta oss</li>
  </ul>          
</div>

#desktop-nav {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

#desktop-nav-menu {
  display: table-row;
}
#desktop-nav-menu .menu-item {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
}

.site-logo {
  min-width: 400px;
}
.site-logo > img {
  width: 400px;
  height: 146px;
  margin: -6px auto 0;
}
```

The logo is and must be at most `400px` wide but can scale as you resize down.

I'm struggling with making the logo appear in the middle, as well as making the `.menu-item`s take up as much space as possible, while getting it to look the desired way. If possible I would like to avoid having fixed widths for the `.menu-item` since the text might become longer or shorter.

It just feels like doing it the way I'm trying to do it is a bit clunky altogether so I would appreciate some assistance.

Comment: Are you using LESS or SASS?

Comment: @Curt I'm using SASS

Comment: have you tried setting the `vertical-align:middle` on your logo?

Comment: Seriously, just post the compiled CSS.  This is not a Sass problem.

Comment: @cimmanon I never said that the SASS was the problem. This basically looks like the compiled CSS... I need to know which properties to put where.

Comment: Can you provide a JSFiddle, so we can play with that?? Would be helpful.

Comment: can you post html code too?

Comment: can u post demo code?

Comment: @LinkinTED Fiddle provided

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yNJQRG

Comment: @Dmitriy How would I make the items be squeezed together as in my image?

Comment: @Chrillewoodz check my answer, demo provided. see if it works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```html
<div id="desktop-nav">
  <ul id="desktop-nav-menu" class="clearfix no-bullet">
    <li id="menu-item-29" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-29">Hem</li>
    <li id="menu-item-27" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-27">Aktiviteter</li>
    <li id="menu-item-26" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-26">Konferenser</li>
    <li id="menu-item-31" class="site-logo menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-31"></li>
    <li id="menu-item-28" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-28">Priser</li>
    <li id="menu-item-25" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-25">Om oss</li>
    <li id="menu-item-24" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-24">Kontakta oss</li>
  </ul>          
</div>
<style>
#desktop-nav {
  display: table;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 50%;
 margin-right: -50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, 0);
 text-align:center;
}

#desktop-nav-menu {
  display: table-row;
}
#desktop-nav-menu .menu-item {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
}

.site-logo {min-width:400px;
}
.site-logo > img {
  width: 400px;
  height: 146px;
  margin: -6px auto 0;
}
</style>
```

I removed `width:100%;` from `#desktop-nav` and replaced it with:

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 50%;
margin-right: -50%;
transform: translate(-50%, 0);
text-align:center;
```

Comment: It works, ish, but I can't add margins to the items when using this. Need to create some space between em so I get it like the image I included.

Comment: Okay, simply add `li{padding:15px;}` !! :)

Comment: The last item jumps down no matter what I do. If I set a specific width then it's not centered anymore. It's the same for all answers here unfortunately.

Comment: The last item? I'm not sure what you mean; it seems fine to me, could you post an image, please?

Comment: Solved it by adding an invisible border instead of padding.

Answer (score 0):

First, you want to vertical-align the menu items. You almost got it, because you already display them as table-cells. But then you float them. Remove that and add a `vertical-align: middle`

```
#desktop-nav-menu .menu-item {
  display: table-cell;
  /*float: left;*/
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}
```

You'll also see that the menu will be as width as the screen. You might want to make it smaller, add a width to `#desktop-nav` and add a `margin: 0 auto` to center it on the page:

```
#desktop-nav {
  width: 850px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-height: 140px;
}
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/tp27e67L/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `display table, table-row and table-cell`

Use `float` instead. It makes design much more flexible. [DEMO](http://cssdeck.com/labs/ktbwsfpj)

Added borders for your reference.

see if this works for you.

```
#desktop-nav {
  display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    margin-right: -50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
    text-align:center;
  border:1px solid red;
  overflow:hidden;
}

#desktop-nav-menu {
  display: inline-block;
  border:1px solid green;
  padding:0px;
}
#desktop-nav-menu .menu-item {
  float:left;
  width:auto;
  text-align: center;
  list-style:none;
  height: 146px;
   line-height: 146px;
  border:1px solid blue;
}

.site-logo {min-width:400px;
  height: 146px;
  border:1px solid red !important;
}
.site-logo > img {
  width: 400px;

  border:1px solid red ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your question, the logo is not an actual menu element but part of the styling. Based on this assumption you should remove the line

```
<li id="menu-item-31" class="site-logo menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-31"></li>
```

altogether as it is usually better to preserve the semantic integrity of the html code.

Instead set the logo as a background image on the menu. Then you can space out the menu elements by using css selectors.

```
#desktop-nav-menu {
    background: url(logo.png) no-repeat 100px 0
}

#desktop-nav-menu .menu-item {
    position: relative;
    left: 100px;
}

#desktop-nav-menu .menu-item:nth-child(1),
#desktop-nav-menu .menu-item:nth-child(2),
#desktop-nav-menu .menu-item:nth-child(3) {
    left: 0px;
}
```

The drawback is that this will only work on one line.